# My Ubuntu machine is just showing a black screen or just loading. this happened before and an system reboot was done, any ideas on what the issue is?

Tags: 20.04, versions

I have already performed a system reboot, when i tried to do it for a second time it didnt work

Comment: What gpu? Can you boot recovery mode? If nVidia turn on network & update driver. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` If installing different driver than before you have to purge before installing new driver. Also other alternatives to reveiw: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)